# Weird faces after i solidify

Tags: mesh, faces, svg

[image]

Hi, I imported a svg into blender and wanted the extude/solidify the image. However when I tried to solidify the white part shown in the image, theres a werid mesh or face. Do anyone know how to fix that or what the weird part is even called? Thanks!

Comment: hello, could you please share the object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/409450e8bda344fc9b665d615a935eac

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these two vertices mess up the topology:

[image]

For the left one, press <kbd>V</kbd>, choose *Aligned*, move it a bit and and move the handles (or even delete it), for the right one, select and move the handle on the X axis so that it doesn't collapse with the vertex:

[image]

And it should work:

[image]